# Pass information between activities

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bundle

I am doing a project where I have to program a pedometer. The pedometer will work using a button and you have to tell the length of your steps. I made a main activity that let you choose between go anonymous an another one that let you register. The aplication works when I register or when I go anonymous, and the step length is passed well to the third activity, an activity where you can press a button and increase the number of steps done and the meters done. In this activity there is another button to configure the length of your steps and I want to pass all the info to the anonymous activity to change only the length of the steps and I pass all the info. I used the method putExtra() and getIntent().getExtra().getString(), but only works going to the main activity to the registe/anonymous activity and then going to the pedometer activity, but when i want to configure the length of the steps the aplications stops.

This is my code for the anonymous activity:

```
if(this.getIntent().hasExtra("name")){
        names=this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
    }else{
        names="";
    }

    if(this.getIntent().hasExtra("user")){
        userName=this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("user");
    }else{
        userName="";
    }

    if(this.getIntent().hasExtra("pass")){
        password=this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("pass");
    }else{
        password="";
    }

    if(this.getIntent().hasExtra("feetBefore")){
        footBefore=this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("feetBefore");
    }else{
        footBefore="0";
    }

    if(this.getIntent().hasExtra("steps")){
        stepsDone=this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("steps");
    }else{
        stepsDone="0";
    }


    Button continueBtn = findViewById(R.id.continueAnonymous);
    foot =  findViewById(R.id.lengthFeetAnonymous);

    continueBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String footSize = String.valueOf(foot.getText());
            if(!footSize.equals("")) {
                Intent mainAnonymous = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main5Activity.class);
                mainAnonymous.putExtra("name", names);
                mainAnonymous.putExtra("user", userName);
                mainAnonymous.putExtra("pass", password);
                mainAnonymous.putExtra("feet", footSize);
                mainAnonymous.putExtra("steps", stepsDone);
                mainAnonymous.putExtra("feetBefore", footBefore);
                startActivity(mainAnonymous);
                finish() ;
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(Main4Activity.this, "You have to complete all the backets.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

This is the code of my pedometer activity:

```
Bundle parameters = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    if(parameters != null){
        name = parameters.getString("name");
        username = parameters.getString("user");
        password = parameters.getString("pass");
        String foot = parameters.getString("feet");
        String footBefore = parameters.getString("feetBefore");
        String stepsDone = parameters.getString("steps");
        if(stepsDone!=null) cont = Integer.parseInt(stepsDone);
        else cont =0;
        if(footBefore!=null)feetBefore = Integer.parseInt(footBefore);
        else feetBefore =0;
        if(foot !=null)feet = Float.parseFloat(foot)/100;
        else feet = (float) 0.43;
        cont2 = cont*feetBefore;
    }else {
        name = "";
        username = "";
        password = "";
        feet = (float) 0.43;
    }

    increase = findViewById(R.id.increaseStep);
    configuration = findViewById(R.id.confBtn);
    saveMain = findViewById(R.id.saveBtnMain);
    resume = findViewById(R.id.resumBtn);

    final TextView steps = findViewById(R.id.stepCounter);
    final TextView km = findViewById(R.id.kilometerCounter);
    steps.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,"%d Steps",cont));
    String aux =String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,"%.2f Meters", cont2);
    km.setText(aux);

    increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cont++;
            steps.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,"%d Steps",cont));
            cont2 += feet;
            String aux =String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,"%.2f Meters", cont2);
            km.setText(aux);
        }
    });

    configuration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent conf = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main4Activity.class);
            conf.putExtra("name", name);
            conf.putExtra("user", username);
            conf.putExtra("pass", password);
            String aux2 = String.valueOf(cont);
            conf.putExtra("steps", aux2);
            float aux4 =feet*100;
            String aux3 = String.valueOf(aux4);
            conf.putExtra("feetBefore", aux3);
            startActivity(conf);
            finish() ;
        }
    });
}
```

I started to learn android yesterday so I don't know what I am doing wrong. If you can help me I would apreciate it. In addition, I think it's something about the bundle.

Comment: Add all data in a bundle and check only if bundle!=null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: Please update the answer with the crash log you are getting

Comment: How Can I get the crash log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all data in a bundle and check only if bundle!=null –by Milan Pansuriya

I don't know the difference between using a bundle to pass al the data and putExtra to my intent but this works for me. Thank you Milan Pansuriya.